# Apple Lion OS X 10.7.3 Update Wifi

Tags: macos, software-update

As soon as I restarted the system after installing the 10.7.3 update, my wifi stopped working. It wouldn't connect. It would get a private ip assigned to it.

So, I switched on and off the wifi, changed the network settings several times by removing the wifi and adding it again, restarted the system, and when all of these didn't help, I phoned Apple support. After asking me to fiddle with the router, computer and several other things, he accepted that the new update was having issues. And I needed to roll back to the old version. Has anyone run into the same problem? Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Many times the [Combo Update](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484) will resolve problems.  Download that update (on another system if you have to) and install it, then restart. I have not seen generalized WiFi issues after the 10.7.3 update, so it is very likely the combo update will help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem even with the combo update. I was able to find a thread on Apple's support forums that described the solution as turning off and on the OS X firewall, however, after booting from Windows (Boot Camp) back into OS X, I found that the issue had resolved itself without further intervention.

Answer (score 0):

I saw exactly the same report about wifi and 10.7.3 in a greek forum.
My opinion, after trying many 'tricks' to deal with this lion problem, is that the only final solution to this problem is to buy an airport express.
Since I bought it, some months ago, I can't remember a single problem with the wireless connection between my macbook pro and the airport express.
If internet is critical for your job (I am a professional developer) the only 100% solution so far is to buy airport express.

Comment: Airport Express is a nice product; however, I would add that an ethernet connection is far closer to 100% in terms of reliability, etc., than wireless.

Answer (score 0):

when waking from sleep tap the power button on the back and it will not lose the internet.  Do not touch the keyboard when waking from sleep.   This is a temp. fix.  Waiting for a solution. Easier than going to system preferences > network> choosing network each time.